# Batch processing in JSON using Youtube API V3

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api

I'm able to use the V3 API to add a single video to a playlist, but I'm having trouble adding multiple videos at once.

To add a single video using the API explorer, my request looks like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?             
part=snippet&fields=id%2Cstatus&key={MY_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer {MY_TOKEN}
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "snippet": {
  "playlistId": "PLsocvUmhlFZlTIR58nIqSAf2Ue1vQWVJO",
  "resourceId": {
   "playlistId": "PLsocvUmhlFZlTIR58nIqSAf2Ue1vQWVJO",
   "videoId": "7Mbnb_LZwDM",
   "kind": "youtube#video"
  }
 }
}
```

I basically want to submit multiple "videoIds" in a single request. I've tried "videoId":["id1","id2","id3"], and the request is successful but only adds the first item in the array.

Comment: which programming language are you talking about ?

Comment: This is just using the API Explorer that Youtube offers -- the actual HTTP request will be written using Python and probably PycUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Data APi v3, currently doesn't support multiple playlistItem inserts at once. Please file a feature request in https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)   and let me know the id as a comment here.

But you can do batch requests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310562/how-to-correctly-use-google-api-python-clients-batchhttprequest

Comment: ID: 5347 
Does v2 support multiple playlistItem inserts at once?

Comment: v3 supports through a batch request. edited my answer. That's currently broken but should be fixed soon.