# Why is only the first youtube playlist updated, when sending in two youtube playlist updates?

Tags: powershell, youtube-data-api

When running the code example below, only the first YouTube playlist ($YouTubePlaylistId1) is updated with an added video ($YouTubeVideoId).

While no update occurs for the second YouTube playlist ($YouTubePlaylistId2).

I don't receive any errors, but could there still be an issue with the json body below? Or is it something else I've missed here?

I've tried to switch around the playlistid, but it's always the first one defined that get's updated.

There's no difference if it's the same playlist id set in both variables: $YouTubePlaylistId1, $YouTubePlaylistId2, with a unique video ($YouTubeVideoId).

Tried multiple variations of the json body ($YouTubePlaylistVideoBody), but that usually ends with an error complaining about the format of the json.

```
# Set the first yt playlist id
$YouTubePlaylistId1 = "DummyPlaylistId1"

# Set the second yt playlist id
$YouTubePlaylistId2 = "DummyPlaylistId2"

# Set the yt video id
$YouTubeVideoId = "dQw4w9WgXcQ"

# Set access token provided by https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
$GoogleAccessToken = "DummyAccessToken"

# Set the rest method to yt playlistitems 
$YouTubePlaylistVideoUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet"

# Set the JSON body 
$YouTubePlaylistVideoBody = @"
{
    "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId1",
    "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        }
    },
    "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId2",
    "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        }
    }
}
"@

# Create new header object
$HeaderValue = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"

# Append the Google access token in $GoogleAccessToken
$HeaderValue.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $GoogleAccessToken")

# Invoke rest command
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $HeaderValue -Uri $Uri -Method "POST" -Body 
$YouTubePlaylistVideoBody -ContentType "application/json"
```

Expected result is that both youtube playlists are updated with an video.

Actual result is that only the first playlist (defined in $YouTubePlaylistVideoBody) is being updated, without any errors reported back.

**Edit:** Attempted to use two different JSON arrays as below, but they all ends with error "(400) Bad Request":

```
$YouTubePlaylistVideoBody = @"
{
    "snippet": [
        "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId1",
        "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        },
        "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId2",
        "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        }
    ]
}
"@

$YouTubePlaylistVideoBody = @"
[
    "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId1",
    "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        }
    },
    "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "$YouTubePlaylistId2",
    "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "$YouTubeVideoId"
        }
    }
]
"@
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to put the snippet objects in the json as an array `[...]` rather than as object?

Comment: Good idea, but I get error "(400) Bad Request" returned when trying to do so. Will see if I can show the format in the main question above. 

I'm starting to believe it's not possible to add several videos in the same request:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216997/batch-processing-in-json-using-youtube-api-v3 

Batch processing does not seem available for youtube data api and if I somehow missed it, it's now being ceased:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch